# How do I check what upgrades my enemy has?

Tags: starcraft-2

Whenever I click an enemy unit, it still keeps the selection on my own unit, so I can't see what upgrades my enemy has. How can I inspect what weapon/armor upgrades his units have?

(It didn't use to work like this in the past. Before the latest patch, it would select an enemy unit if i clicked on it)

Comment: Not *quite* A duplicate, mind.

Comment: @Shadur - **Actually is it.**  It has the exact same answer just a different interface because the patch was released.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to check `Enable Enemy Unit Selection`, which is a new option unselected by default as of patch 2.0.4.

It's in options, under gameplay, the bottom-most checkbox on the right.

This will allow you to select enemy and neutral units in the map.

See screenshot:

[image: screenshot showing the Enable Enemy Unit Selection option]

You may also be interested in changing some other new settings, see [this thread on Blizzard's forums](http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/forum/topic/7923493743)

> **Uncheck Enable Simple Command Card** - Will bring back the good ol' command card with partrol, hold position, and all the other classic commands.
>
> **Uncheck Select All Larvae** - Will allow you to click on a single Zerg larva, should you choose.
>
> **Check Enable Enemy Unit Selection** - Will allow you to select enemy units and structures.
>
> If you're a purist:
>
> **Uncheck Enable Starting Worker Rally** - Will allow you to assign your workers manually at the start of a match, just like in previous versions of the game.
>
> **Uncheck Display Experience Points** - Will stop the XP points from popping up over kills and such while you're in a match. (XP is still earned.)
>
> **Uncheck Always Show Worker Status** - Will only display worker counters on "town halls" and Vespene Gas structures when cursor is hovering over it.

Comment: Argh... Sorry. So simple... Can't believe I missed that.

Comment: It drives me nuts that they would have that option turned off by DEFAULT. Really weird decision by Blizzard.

Comment: What's the point of this anyway?

Comment: @BrianOrtiz - They likely discovered more people turned it off then left it enabled.

Comment: @Ramhound I mean why would not want to be able to select enemy units?