# Why can't I click enemy units anymore?

Tags: starcraft-2

Ever since I installed HotS, I've been unable to select enemy units.  Is this a new feature with the expansion or did is there an option to change that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I check what upgrades my enemy has?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/106383/how-do-i-check-what-upgrades-my-enemy-has)

Comment: This one has the better title and is asking about the basic problem, I'd prefer to close the other as a dupe of this.

Comment: @MBraedley I would agree with Matthew that this one should be kept open.  In 22 hours this one has gotten 297 views where the other was posted 20 days ago and only has 375 views.  The other one has a bad title which is why I didn't notice the similarities in our questioning.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is a new feature in Heart of the Swarm which was introduced in the Beta.

It is default set to not enable Enemy Unit selection.

It can be changed in the Gameplay options.

[image: Options -> Gameplay -> Enable Enemy Units Selection]

Comment: It's a misnomer, because turning it off also prevents you from selecting neutral creatures, mineral patches, and other things.

Comment: @Blem How do I get the interface to be some colour other than blue? It’s amber in your screenshot.

Answer (score 5):

http://eu.battle.net/sc2/en/forum/topic/6160898784

I found out its an option in the menus.
Options -> Gameplay -> Enable Enemy Units Selection
[image: Options -> Game Play -> Enable Enemy Units Selection]

I'm not sure why Blizzard doesn't make by default.